# Java - Using scanner to read in specific type

Tags: java, class, object

```
public void loadTill() throws IOException {
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader(SHOP_TILL_DATA_FILE));


    int tillSize = infile.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0;i<tillSize*2;i++){


    UKDenomination ct =infile.next();
    int nc = infile.nextInt();

    DenominationFloat m = new DenominationFloat(ct, nc);

    till.addFloat(m);
    }

}
```

I would like ct to be of type UKDenomination, I'm new to java and haven't quite got the grasp of it....

NOTE: UKDENOMINATION IS AN ENUM

There is multiple methods where UKdenomination is declared as shown below
1)

```
public static UKDenomination fromString(String strValue)
```

2)

```
private UKDenomination(int v) {
        value = v;
    }
```

3)

```
public enum UKDenomination {
```

Comment: Can you show us how infile looks and how UKDenomination is declared?

Comment: next will return a string; if UKDenomination has a constructor like `UKDenomination(String)` you could do something like `UKDenomination ct = new UKDenomination( infile.next());` (assuming infile is a Scanner object)

Comment: @zlopez it has been updated, sorry for the three versions...

Comment: ok so your gonna need `UKDenomination ct = UKDenomination.fromString( infile.next());`

Comment: @BenKnoble I tried that but it states 'cannot instantiate the type UKDenomination' Thank you for your replies it is much appreciated

Comment: @BenKnoble I tried the second comment but now states "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instantiate your object, then fill it using your method, try the following:

```
UKDenomination ct = new UKDenomination();
ct = ct.fromString( infile.next());
```

**EDIT:**

If it's an Enum, so you can't save the input as a new type of this enum, because referring to the [**Oracle Enum Docs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) there's only one constructor and we can't use it (it's only used by the compiler):

> **protected Enum(String name, int ordinal)**
>
> Sole constructor. Programmers cannot invoke this constructor. It is
> for use by code emitted by the compiler in response to enum type
> declarations. Parameters:
>
> name - - The name of this enum constant, which is the identifier used
> to declare it.
>
> ordinal - - The ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in
> the enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an
> ordinal of zero).

Comment: I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot instantiate the type UKDenomination

Comment: Do you have the UKDenomination() constructor without parameters? if not , implement it,

Comment: No, I'm talking about the default constructor the one without arguments, because when you have constructors that have arguments you have to write the default constructor (which is normally automatically accessible with classes), because when you have other constructors this one will be unreachable and you have to write it yourself.

Comment: My default constructor is number three, this holds the two other methods...... I hope I make sense or otherwise I'm just completely wrong..

Comment: No it's : 
`public UKDenomination() { 
}`

Comment: When I try to create it, I get this error - Illegal modifier for the enum constructor; only private is permitted.

Comment: `UKDenomination` is an Enum or a class?

Comment: In that case you can't save it as a new type of your Enum.